# Animation stopping object rendering on Android device

Tags: unity-game-engine

If I create a blank scene, add a cube and attach an `Animation Controller` to it, then create a blank `Animation` and add that to the `Animation Controller` and then run the game in the editor - all is good.

If I then edit the `Animation` to spin the cube in the editor and run - all is still good.

My problem is, if I then push this to my attached Android device, the cube is not rendered - even though it is rendered in the editor.

The issue has something to do with the animation clip itself, as the cube will render on the Android device if an animation clip is empty.

If there is somewhere practical to upload the sample scene file, let me know and I'll do that.

Comment: What happens if you make a PC build (or an executable for whatever platform you're on)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug starting in Unity 3D 5.3.0. I submitted this to Unity and they have just responded:

> Thanks for reporting the issue.
>
> We have fixed this and problem should not appear in the latest version
>   (5.3.2p3).  If you are still able to reproduce it on the latest
>   version of Unity, please respond to this email.